# How many inputs should have a Multilayer Perceptron to find out the language from given text?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I pretend to use Tensorflow (by Python) to implement a small system that it must to return the language from a given text (1-20 words).

I know Multilayer Perceptron is good for classification problem and I think this is a good network topology for my purpose.

I will have to decide how many layers and how many nodes are in each layer, but I do not know how mane inputs my network should have.

Can anybody help me with the network inputs for this kind of problem?

Comment: I wrote some tensorflow code for language identification here. https://github.com/ajaech/twitter_langid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear what you mean by inputs.

But in this problem inputs are the text that you want to classify. So given some text, "I want to classify this as english" you might encode this using char n-grams e.g

```
if n = 2, ==> 'I ', ' w', 'wa', 'an' etc.
```

You would then have to map these n-grams to indices by using a dictionary of n-grams. which would vectorize the text for e.g

```
{1 : 'I ', 2: 'En', ... }
```

You can use a library [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html) of [spacy](https://spacy.io/) to help build this 
dictionary or you can write the code yourself, of course.

"I want to classify this as english" might map to a vector of indices

```
[1, 17, 45, 7, 9, 10, 5, 4, ...]
```

that then could be an input to an embedding layer, which could be then fed to a MLP.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. I wanted to say exactly that. I always use neural network with number's vector. Thanks so much.